# Estimation of the percentage of windows OS users using .net 3.0?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, estimation

I am building a web application that has very high requirement. I wanted to build it first in silverlight and activex, with javascript breaching between them. Later I started considering using [xbap](http://www.xbap.org/faq.html). The problem is that xbap demands .net 3.0, and before starting to write an application with such demands I wanted to have a general understanding on the amount of window OS users who have .net framework 3.0 installed. Does anyone has an idea? where can I find such estimations? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have statistics for your website (or feel like coding up such), .NET versions will be sent as part of the `User-Agent` for IE and Firefox (atleast, I don't use any other browsers, so can't speak for them) by default. You can then get statistics for the people that actually matter: your users.

That aside (or if you don't have a public website at all yet), then you can always do detection code and tell people to go download it if they need it. If you have a site/application that people want to use, most if not all won't begrudge downloading a browser plugin or two.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you really want is the percentage of *your* users that have .net 3.0. Do you have a website already? This information is given in the user-agent.

Comment: No, I don't have a website yet and what I am writing should be the center of my website. I was thinking of embadding my project as a facebook app first, so I guess it's a percentage of facebook users?

Comment: I'd imagine facebook would have those sorts of numbers. If you asked very, very nicely they might give them to you.

Comment: I don't know... any other way to get around this? Are there any websites specializing in this area?

Comment: Probably but none that I would know without searching. My best guess would by that the number of people that have it is maybe 3% of users. But an analytics site will have the info, for sure.

Comment: 3%? that's it? that sounds terribly low, the amount of vista users is higher than 3% and they have .net 3.0 installed automatically. Is there any good site to check these things out ?

Comment: Ah, well, shows how much I know :) I can't think of a good site, I'd just search. Alexa.com maybe? I don't know.